# Emails sent using Gmail API are being flagged as phishy by Gmail

Tags: gmail-api

When I send an email using the *Gmail API*, recipients that are using the Gmail web interface are getting a `phishing` warning when they open the email.

However, when I send the exact same email content through the same Gmail account but using the *web UI*, the recipients do not get the `phishing` warning.

The only difference I can find between the two received emails, is that the one sent using the API has this additional header:

```
Received: from 114692869688 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Tue, 11 Jun 2019 11:37:51 -0500
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
When defining your message does not define the from parameter :

```py
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  #message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  encoded_message = urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  return {'raw': encoded_message.decode()}
```

In fact, this parameter is also defined when giving the user_id to the send method.

```py
message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
                .execute())
```

Comment: It should be `message['From'] = ...`, not `messages['from'] = ...` (even though Google's Python guide shows the lower-case form).

Answer (score 2):

In my case recipients get the emails ok, but senders got their own messages flagged as phishing in their sent messages tray.

After some time struggling with this, it seems a case-sensitive issue.

Once I capitalized the **f** in the "from" header the problem went away.

So:

```py
# sender something like "John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>"
message['From'] = sender
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your from-header is `['From']`, and not `['from']` (like Google's guide shows).

This one-line diff:

```
@@ -129,7 +129,7 @@ def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
     """
     message = MIMEText(message_text)
     message["To"] = to
-    message["from"] = sender
+    message["From"] = sender
     message["Subject"] = subject
     return {"raw": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode("ascii")}
```

Is the difference between getting this failure:

[image]

and this success:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are [two options](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185812?hl=en):

1. Send an email through Gmail SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, a protocol for sending e-mail messages between servers)
2. [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) - All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data.

When you get an email that looks suspicious, here are a few things to [check for](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8253?hl=en):

- Check that the email address and the sender name match.
- Check if the [email is authenticated](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707).
- Hover over any links before you click on them. If the URL of the link doesn't match the description of the link, it might be leading you to a phishing site.
- Check the [message headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436) to make sure the "from" header isn't showing an incorrect name.**

Yes, the message header is important when sending an email using Gmail API. You will need to trace an email with its full headers.