# How to set display name when sending with GMail API?

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api, email-headers

With the Gmail API, if you do not provide a FROM header, the FROM header is set to the sender's email address. If I set the FROM header to any of the following forms, Gmail displays a phishing warning to my recipients, stating "Be careful with this message. Gmail could not verify that it actually came from [...]":

> name <me@gmail.com>
>
> 'name' <me@gmail.com>
>
> "name" <me@gmail.com>

where *name* is in exactly the same form as my display name.

Is there any way to send my display name without creating the phishing warning?

Comment: I was struggling with this behavior ("error") when I first tried to send an email, even to myself as a test. I found the casing of the from-header matters, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804634/246801.